# Пароли Drupal: шифрование для проверки

Tags: drupal, база-данных, php, пароль

Делаю сайт не на друпале, и нужно сделать вход юзера. База данных от Дрюпала 7.
Как шифровать пароль для проверки?

*Drupal 7*

Comment: дрюпал :))))

Comment: так может и вызывать функции  создания позьзователя из Drupal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если друпал установлен и сам движок работает, то  можно примерно так:

1. подключаем друпал

   ```
   $path_to_drupal = "/var/www/DRUPAL_FOLDER";
   define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $path_to_drupal); //устанавливаем константу DRUPAL_ROOT так как она используется в бутстрап
   require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';//подключаем сам бутстрап
   require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/password.inc';// в этом файле собраны все функции для работы с паролями
   drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); // стартуем друпал
   ```
2. Далее выбираем из базы пользователей

   ```
   $query = db_select('users', 'u');

   $query
       ->condition('u.uid', 0, '<>')
       ->fields('u', array('uid', 'pass'));

   $result = $query->execute();
   ```
3. Выдергиваем хэши паролей и сравниваем с тем, что пришло с формы

   ```
   foreach ($result as $users) {
       $stored_hash = $users->pass;
       $new_pass = $_POST['form_password_field'];// тут то, что пришло с формы

       $hash = _password_crypt('sha512', $new_pass, $stored_hash);

       if ($hash && $stored_hash == $hash) {
           echo 'PASSWORD CORRECTLY';
       } else {
           echo 'YOU WRONG';
       }
   }
   ```

Если друпал не установлен, но нужно использовать его базу пользователей, то из `/includes/password.inc` переписываем функции `_password_crypt` и `user_check_password`, подставляя свои переменные.

`salt` находится в конфигурационном файле `settings.php`